# How to add Bootstrap to Vue.js TreeView Example

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, treeview

The code for a Vue.js [treeview](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html) looks like this:

HTML:

```
<!-- item template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <div
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      v-on:click="toggle"
      v-on:dblclick="changeType">
      {{model.name}}
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{open ? '-' : '+'}}]</span>
    </div>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item
        class="item"
        v-for="model in model.children"
        :model="model">
      </item>
      <li class="add" v-on:click="addChild">+</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

<p>(You can double click on an item to turn it into a folder.)</p>

<!-- the demo root element -->
<ul id="demo">
  <item
    class="item"
    :model="treeData">
  </item>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
// demo data
var data = {
  name: 'My Tree',
  children: [
    { name: 'hello' },
    { name: 'wat' },
    {
      name: 'child folder',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'hello' },
            { name: 'wat' }
          ]
        },
        { name: 'hello' },
        { name: 'wat' },
        {
          name: 'child folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'hello' },
            { name: 'wat' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// define the item component
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    model: Object
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function () {
      return this.model.children &&
        this.model.children.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
      }
    },
    changeType: function () {
      if (!this.isFolder) {
        Vue.set(this.model, 'children', [])
        this.addChild()
        this.open = true
      }
    },
    addChild: function () {
      this.model.children.push({
        name: 'new stuff'
      })
    }
  }
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    treeData: data
  }
})
```

Is there any way I can add Bootstrap styling to this, to make the treeview look something like the first example below:

[image]

I have very little frontend experience and don't really understand where to put the CSS here. I don't really understand the part of the code where it's mixed script and cshtml (inside `<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">`).

Answer (score 0):

To add bootstrap to your page just include their source files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As far as those specific styles, I'm not going to fully setup your UI, that isn't what stack overflow is for.  You can follow along with the instructions on this github which should get you close:

https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

Comment: I've already looked at that, it does not use Vue. I just wanted one example of where I would put the css, not the full setup. Just showing me how to import stylesheets is not that relevant to my question, in my opinion.

Comment: So bootstrap has the css included.  If you see in the code I posted the first link is their css file.  In that file they have classes that apply different styles to the elements you attach the class.  So if you wanted to add a bootstrap style to an element in your html you would need to add a class to that element.  I.e. class="bootstrapClass".  If you already have working JavaScript then you could just use the css files and classes from the link I attached.